# How can I append to the class name when my selector has a pseudo class?

Tags: sass

So I write my css trough sass (scss). I use the ampersand mark (&) to target children. However, when I'm doing a hover state of a certain element I cannot the children anymore. Is there a way to do this?

To be clear: I want to target the children by their class, not by their element (eg: span).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__inner">
       <p class="container__inner__paragraph">
       foo to the
       <span class="container__inner__paragraph__highlight">
       bar
      </span>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.container{
  &__inner{
    &__paragraph{
      color: yellow;
      background: black;

      &:hover{
        background: rgba(0,0,0, .3);

        // This obviously works
        span{
          color: green;
        }

        // This obviously works too
        .container__inner__paragraph__higlight{
          color: green;
        }

        // This however doesn't work
        &__highlight{
          color: green;
        }
      }

      &__highlight{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A codepen that hopefully explains my struggle:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZqGPq

Comment: It's not clear here what your expected result should be, you've just shown what you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @simey.me I found the proper solution. If you add an ampersand (&-mark) behind the &:hover you can target children classes in the ampersand way.

Codepen for the lovers! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZqGPq

The scss:

```
.container{
  &__inner{
    &__paragraph{
      color: yellow;
      background: black;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 4rem;

      &:hover &{
        &__highlight{
          color: green;  
        }
      }

      &__highlight{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way:

```
.container__inner__paragraph {
  &:hover &__highlight {
    background: red!important;
  }
}
```

But I'm not 100% sure what you want?

Comment: This set me on my way! It's not entirely correct but it gave me a push in the right direction! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class name as you are doing right now, your code is correct, you only have a typo error, in your scss you have `.container__inner__paragraph__higlight` but the correct class name is `.container__inner__paragraph__highlight`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOJEdE

Comment: I had a typo indeed, sorry about that. However the thing i want to accomplish is not using the entire class name. That was the whole point of my question. Found the solution tho (below). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to style the highlight class when you hover on the paragraph tag:

.highlight & {color: blue;}